# Can't open a new in and out file with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I'd like to open a new readable and writable file with fstream. I tried to do like the code below, but it failed because the file didn't exist.

```
file.open(file_path, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Is there any good way to do this with a new file?

I wrote the code below but it seemed ugly.

```
    file.open(file_path, ios::out | ios::binary);
    file.close();
    file.open(file_path, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Comment: So... why the C tag?

Comment: Check the table [in this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open).

Comment: Sorry, c tag was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to overwrite file that already exists you should use:

```
file.open(file_path, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
```

Appending to such a file:

```
file.open(file_path, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. But using `ios::app`, the code get stopped while executing read sometimes. I just wanted to leave a note.